# concatenating string inside view using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a variable json in the controller, which has an array of 'element', I want to display all element in the same tr tag, with an ' ' between two element. I want to do the following example :

```
element1 element2 element3 element4 element5 element6
```

What is the best approach to do this? I want do this in the view without using the controller, neither scope.

Below, I copy the code of my view, I want to do something like this (it doesn't work)

```
 <div ng-repeat="element in data.elements">
  {{ element }}
 </div>
```

And the data.elements look like this :

```
"elements": ["element_1", "element_1","element_2","element_3","element_4","element_5","element_6",  ]
```

Note : elements is an object inside of data.

Comment: you could do `{{data.elements.join(' ')}}`

Comment: it works exactly that I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting to not have to use a controller, then your data should be formatted exactly how you want it when you bind it to your view. (AKA Already Formatted how you want it).

Otherwise, the entire point of a controller is to separate the data operations and logic from your view.

At the least, define your controller inline in a script tag if you can't reference an external javascript file (which I'm guessing is your problem [due to cms restrictions or whatever]).

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  angular.module('nameOfYourAppModule').controller('ProperlyNamedViewController',[viewControllerFn]);

  function viewControllerFn() {
    vm = this;
    vm.data = {"elements": ["element_1", "element_1","element_2","element_3","element_4","element_5","element_6",  ]}

    vm.returnFormattedElements = function returnFormattedElementsFn() {
      return vm.data.elements.join(" ");
    }

  }
</script>
```

And in your HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ProperlyNamedViewController as viewModelSoIDontUseScope"> 
    {{ viewModelSoIDontUseScope.returnFormattedElements() }}
</div>
```

You could also simply do `{{ data.elements.join(' ') }}` if this is too messy and you don't want to use a controller.